Why does my model even in flat shading look weird?
I am trying to model a helmet. However, for some reason, the shading looks weird even for the flat shading regime. It seems that it tries to visualize more faces/quads than there actually are. This is the model with no modifiers applied (in edit mode):

I tried: recalculating normals, and merging duplicate vertices, but nothing helped. Any ideas?

Hello, if Gordon's answer doesn't answer, please share your object

Hard to tell without inspecting your file if there is more geometry than it should. But this doesn't look like duplicate geometry to me, there are no strange edges showing or something. It looks as if some parts throw shadows at the others. Maybe you have accidentally enabled Shadow in the Overlays for the Viewport Shading. This is an option available for Solid mode:


thanks!! indeed it was the problem.
